# How to edit or install the framework file in Xcode via Carthage?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, ios-frameworks, carthage

How can I edit or install the framework swift file in Xcode via Carthage?

In this screenshot only have 2 file, Why? How to install the swift file in it? So that I can modify it.

[image]

What I want to do is change some code in PieChartRenderer.swift. What I want to modify: [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507228/allow-piechartview-to-hide-value-line-for-tiny-slices-in-swift/47516905?noredirect=1#comment82003824_47516905)

File location:
Carthage > Checkout > Charts > Source > Charts > Renderer > PieChartRenderer.swift

I followed Usage on the README.md. I have completed this 4 step.

1. Drag the `Charts.xcodeproj` to your project
2. Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework
3. `@import Charts`
4. - (Xcode 8.2+) Under "Build Options", mark "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries"

> Current problem: I Dragged the `Charts.xcodeproj` from Checkout to my
>   project. The code is work when I run it on stimulator. But when I stop
>   it and open it again, the value line show up again. On real device,
>   the modified code is no effect... Why?

[image]

Sorry, I'm new in Carthage.

Answer (score 0):

The source is under the Carthage folder: Carthage/Checkouts/Frameworkname/source

Comment: Got screenshot? Because I can't see show package content option when I right click the charts.framework in Xcode. But I saw it when right click the charts.xcodeproj on finder.

Comment: Ya, I edited the code in there but no effect. @DevB2F

Answer (score -2):

1 cd [project_name]

2 carthage build --no-skip-current

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#carthagebuild

Comment: KittipongKJ Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.